# Sonarqube 4.5 provisioning / authorization

Tags: sonarqube

We are using Sonhrqube 4.5 that is integrated into Google's oAuth sign-on. There are no issues with logging in (Authentication). Certain users have been provisioned with sonar-administrators role. But for some reason, the admin role keeps dropping for some users (leaves the user with sonar-users role). We have tried granting them admin access again, but it keeps happening. Also tried creating a brand new group and assigning that group to the user, but still same thing happens. Any thoughts? If you need any other information, let me know.

Just additional info, not sure if it matters - We are using the sonar-oauth-plugin from JCERTIFLab for integration with Google's signon/oauth. This plugin automatically creates users with default role - sonar-users.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be an issue with the Sonar plugin used for integration with google's Oauth. Every time a user is authenticated, permissions get overwritten. To overcome the problem temporarily, we predefined a list of users with admin access in the properties file.